# Analytical form of entropy for the 1D $XY$-model with zero external magnetic field and no periodic boundary conditions

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, spin-models

I'm trying to find the analytical equation for the entropy of the 1-dimensional $XY$-model.

Comment: Are you familiar with transfer matrices? This potentially sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Is this the classical XY or the quantum one?